# Displaying multiple values in for statement in Swift

Tags: swift, loops

Hi I am new to programming.  I apologize beforehand if this is a stupid question, but I'm learning about For loops. The below is an example code I understand.  I know how to write a basic For loop that iterates through a single variable in each loop, but how do I use a For loop to display multiple values in one loop. Example:

```
let treeArray = ["Pine", "Oak", "Yew", "Maple", "Birch", "Myrtle"]

    for tree in treeArray {
    print(tree)
}
```

I want to be able to print three variables in one loop so the code would print

`Pine Oak Yew` on one line

`Maple Birch Myrtle` and on the next

Instead of

```
Pine
Oak
Yew
Maple
Birch
Myrtle
```

Thanks!

Comment: Think about how you would do it by-hand: you would have one loop inside the other, and the inner loop goes from 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.enumerated()` to pair the index with the element and then  `print(_:terminator:)` using `index % 3` to select the appropriate terminator (newline `"\n"` or space `" "`):

```
let treeArray = ["Pine", "Oak", "Yew", "Maple", "Birch", "Myrtle"]

for (index, tree) in treeArray.enumerated() {
    print(tree, terminator: index % 3 == 2 ? "\n" : " ")
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Pine Oak Yew
> Maple Birch Myrtle
> ```

---

**The general case: printing `n` items per line**

In general, for printing `n` items per line:

```
print(tree, terminator: index % n == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ")
```

or equivalently:

```
print(tree, terminator: (index + 1) % n == 0 ? "\n" : " ")
```

---

If you want the last item to always be followed by a newline, then add an addition check for that:

```
print(tree, terminator: index % n == n - 1 || index == treeArray.endIndex - 1 ? "\n" : " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store trees and

```
joined(separator: String)
```

on array to stitch them together.

```
let treeArray = ["Pine", "Oak", "Yew", "Maple", "Birch", "Myrtle"]

var treeNames = [String]()
for (count, tree) in treeArray.enumerated() {
    treeNames.append(tree)
    if ((count + 1) % 3) == 0 {
        let treeLine = treeNames.joined(separator: " ")
        print(treeLine)
        treeNames.removeAll()
    }
}
```